# Phonegap: Display Multiple Images from Phone Album

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make use of the phonegap(cordova) function to display photos from the users album within a very simple app.

The way it is working so far is that the user can pick a photo from the album, which then is displayed.

What I want to achieve is to have another button so that the user can then add another image from his album underneath the first one (not replace the first one). Is there any way of doing this? [In

Any help would be appreciated :)

Here is the code without any of the design etc.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 var pictureSource; // picture source
 var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

 // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
 document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

 // Cordova is ready to be used!
 function onDeviceReady() {
   pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
   destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
 }

 // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
 function capturePhoto() {
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, allowEdit : true,
   destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
 }

 // Called if something bad happens. 
 function onFail(message) {
   alert('Failed because: ' + message);
 }

 function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
   // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
   // console.log(imageData);

   // Get image handle
   var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

   // Unhide image elements
   largeImage.style.display = 'block';

   // Show the captured photo
   // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
   largeImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
 }

 // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
 function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
   // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
   // console.log(imageURI);

   // Get image handle
   var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

   // Unhide image elements
   largeImage.style.display = 'block';

   // Show the captured photo
   // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
   largeImage.src = imageURI;
 }
 // A button will call this function to retrieve photos from the album
 function getPhoto(source) {

   // Retrieve image file location from specified source
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
     destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
     sourceType: source });
 }
</script>


<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="content"> 
  <button data-theme="d" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Browse     Photos</button> 
  <img style="display:none;width:100%;" id="largeImage" src="" /> <br>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have only included the JQuery Mobile CSS so you need to include JQuery and JQuery Mobile JS files.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Then what I would do is change the onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) function. Instead of changing the src of an already existing img element you could create it dynamically every-time you retrieve a new image and add it to a new div.

To do this first we will change your html to.

```
<div data-role="content"> 
<button data-theme="d" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">Browse          Photos</button> 
<div id="photos"></div>
</div>
```

Then we can change your function as follows.

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
// Uncomment to view the image file URI 
// console.log(imageURI);

// Create new Image element
var img = $('<img />');
img.attr('src', imageURI);

// Append new img to our photos div
img.appendTo('#photos');

}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can get rid of the big "loading" underneath the photos?

Comment: Not sure why you're seeing a loading underneath the photos. Can you explain more? Try wrapping your content div in another div with data-role="page" attribute. This is what you should be doing for each JQuery Mobile page.